# Data updated while iterating and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, multithreading, executorservice

Hi I have the following statement:

1. We have 1 background thread that reads data from database **(MySQL)** every 5 minutes and loads this data into a **static Map<String, List < String >>**
2. We have a main while(true) which iterates over this Map<String,List< String >> the reference is gotten like this: **Manager.getInstance().getDataMap();**

The following code is executed:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = Manager.getInstance().getDataMap();

data.forEach((s, values) -> {
  logger.info("Info Key -> {}", s);
  for (String value : values) {
      executorService.execute(new TT(value));
  }
});
```

As you can see we have an executor service which is defined like this:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(concurrent);
ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(concurrent, concurrent, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);

// when the blocking queue is full, this tries to put into the queue which blocks
executorService.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, executor) -> {
    try {
        // block until there's room
        executor.getQueue().put(r);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RejectedExecutionException("Producer thread interrupted", e);
    }
});
```

This program process each value of each key and it can take a lot of time for each one.
The thing I want to accomplish is when making an update into the database like removing or creating or modify a new entry then update the iteration so that values are added or removed in the same iteration since we can take up to N minutes so that the reference of the map is updated.

Comment: Rather than poll the database, have the database send out notifications whenever a change to its data occurs. If you [edit] your question and add the database you are using, I may be able to explain how to get that database to send notifications.

Comment: The architecture is a bit dubious. You have a database from which you do bulk selects and process the results, but the database can be modified during that time and you're required to be notified of those changes and act on them. It sounds like you should be looking into some sort of queuing solution instead.

Comment: @Abra done. I am using MySQL

Comment: @Kayaman could you give me an example

Comment: maybe this can help: https://github.com/Cyclonecode/mysql-notification .... and probably for a better solution we need to know the architecture of your app clearly. I mean how is db changing, is it through an app or direct execution of SQL script.